# Replacing a Sentence

Tags: c++

write a program that will read in a sentence of up to 100 characters and output the sentence with spacing corrected and with letters corrected for capitalization. In other words, in the output sentence all strings of two or more blanks should be compressed to a single blank. The sentence should start with an uppercase letter but should contain no other uppercase letters. Do not worry about proper names; if their first letter is changed to lowercase, that is acceptable. Treat a line break as if it were blank in the sense that a line break and any number of blanks are compressed to a single blank. Assume that the sentence ends with a period and contains no other periods. For example, the input

the    Answer to life, the Universe, and   everything IS 42.

should produce the following output:

The answer to life, the universe, and everything is 42.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const int MAX = 100;
  char sentence[MAX+1];
  string replace = "";
  int space = 0;
  cout<<"Enter a sentence";
  cin.getline(sentence,MAX+1);
  int i =0;
  while(i<MAX && sentence[i] != '\0' && sentence[i] != '.')
  {
    if(isspace(sentence[i]) || sentence[i] == '.')
    {
      space++;
    }
    else{
      space = 0;
    }
    if(space < 2)
    {
      replace += tolower(sentence[i]);
    }
  }

if(replace.length()>0)
{
replace.at(0) = toupper(replace.at(0));
if(replace[replace.length()-1]=='' && replace.length()==1){
replace=replace;
}
else if(replace[replace.length()-1]=='')
{
  replace[replace.length()-1]='.';
}
else if(replace.length()==MAX)
{
  replace[MAX-1]='.';
}
else
{
  replace+='.';
}
}

cout<<"The sentence to enter: "<<endl << sentence<<endl;
cout<<"How it should be: "<<replace<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

And my errors are:

```
Errors:
 warning: unknown escape sequence '\O'
      [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
  while(i<MAX && sentence[i] != '\O' && sentence[i] != '.')
                                 ^~
] warning: empty character constant [-Winvalid-pp-token]
    if(isspace(sentence[i]) || sentence[i] == '')
                                              ^
 error: expected expression
 warning: empty character constant [-Winvalid-pp-token]
if(replace[replace.length()-1] == '' && replace.length()=='')
                                  ^
33:35: error: expected expression
 warning: empty character constant [-Winvalid-pp-token]
if(replace[replace.length()-1] == '' && replace.length()=='')
```

How do I fix these ones?

Comment: `empty character constant` should be obvious. You can't have an empty character by putting two single quotes back to back.

Comment: if you are permitted to use `std::string` why do you use `char sentence[MAX+1];` `std::string sentence;` would be a better choice.

Comment: @drescherjm what do i put in place of the empty characters

Comment: You need to remove characters from the string (and shift the string to the left) not try to place empty characters into it.

Comment: `\O` is not the same thing as `\0`

Comment: @selbie noticed that and changed it

Comment: @drescherjm honestly not sure how to do that

Comment: Is the requirement just have to do with spacing and casing of starting character?
If it is, why not just lower case everything first then uppercase the first character? For spacing, you can  just replace all space characters with " ";

Answer (score 0):

```
if(replace[replace.length()-1]=='' && replace.length()==1){
replace=replace;
}
```

I don't know what you are trying to do here, but `''` is not a valid character and is the source of your compiler error. I don't know if you were looking for the null char `\0` or something else, but since the entire expression results in `replace=replace`, the above code is essentially unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

[Compilation results on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EYTVkq).

You are not actually getting an error about `'\O'` - and your code doesn't have `'\O'`... it has ``` '\0`` (zero instead of big-Oh). '\0 ``` [actually has a meaning](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) - the termination character for C-style strings, whose integral value is 0; but there's no escape sequence `'\O'`.

Also, there is no such thing as an "empty single character", so `''` is meaningless. Try to be more explicit, when writing the code, in describing what it is you're checking for. For example, if I were to write:

```
bool my_string_ends_with_a_period = (not my_string.empty()) and (my_string.back() == '.');
```

I'm saying what it is that I'm computing. You don't always have to be this verbose, but right now your code is a bit messy so it's difficult to figure out what you are trying to do.